# How to destroy OTHER game object on collision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col){
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Throwable") {
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }
}
```

This just destroys the gameobject who has script on it. But I want to destroy other object that collides with this object. Couldn't find the answer. I think there is an answer on unity3d(I assume from title) but somehow I can't connect the site.
Also I tried them

```
Destroy (other.gameobject);
Destroy (gameObject.tag == "Throwable");
```

Didn't work anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col){
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Throwable") {
        Destroy (col.gameObject);
    }
}
```

where `col.gameObject` it the incoming GameObject involved in the collision.